# Locked file while second work

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a code which is similar this:

```
string path = "img.jpg";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

//...

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(@"http://www....com/img.jpg"), path);
}
```

But on the line with `DownloadFile` it throws exception

`The process cannot access the file .../img.jpg because it is being used by another process.`

everytime. What's wrong?

Comment: please provide the details of the excepction (the stack trace or cause) so we can help you

Comment: You are doing something else with that file, like displaying it in a PictureBox or having it opened in an image viewer.  Don't do that.

Comment: Emetrop I updated my answer based on what you updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more control over what is happening change that `using` to a `try/catch`

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient()
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(@"http://www....com/img.jpg"), path);
}
catch (Excepcion ex)
{
    //Debug here or set the text of some control to ex.Message to see what is causing the problem
}
finally
{
    //dispose client
}
```

**UPDATE**

Is probably your own process that is keeping a reference to that file.

What is the point to read all the bytes of your local file and then replace that file with and image from the web. I think you only need to do one of those

Comment: Actually I catch the exception on a higher level but it doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: If you dont post the details of your excpetion is hard to solve the problem and also improve the title of the question